# How to differntiate with "кого" и "кому"

Tags: грамматика, узус

How do I know when should I use мне или меня 
тебе тебя?

Comment: "мне / тебе" is Dative case; "меня / тебя" is Accusative and Genitive. It turns out that you're asking about the usage of three of six main cases within a single question. Don't expect anything useful from this.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a simple rule for choosing the correct case. Most beginners try to do this, but it cannot be done. They do not make progress until they stop viewing the case system as an annoying obstacle to be overcome by clever hacks and recognize it as a powerful tool for expressing their thoughts. The cases are labels attached to the names of the actors in the sentence in order to show what the role of each is in the action. Learn what each cases means and then observe how they are used to express ideas. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Мне" и "тебе" is the dative case:

```
 "To whom? - to me". "Кому? - мне".
```

"Меня и тебя" is genitive:

```
"For whom? - for you". "From whom? - from me". 
"Для кого? - Для тебя". "От кого? - От меня".
```

Comment: but both of them have a very close meaning i cant learn how to differntiate between them in my sentence i always use меня instead of мне

Comment: Can you differentiate between "for me" and "to me"? How do you decide when to use which?

Comment: okay. example if i want to say can you understand me? this me is what ?

Comment: Ah, yeah ... :) Try asking a question. "Можешь ли ты понять КОГО? - меня". When you ask "кого?", the answer is "меня". If the question is "кому", then it is "мне".

Comment: i know that but i dont know when to know if its the kavo or kamy

Comment: Most of the time that trick with English preposition works, so you can use that. When it doesn't, you are going to have to go on a case-by-case basis. 
You could try and develop some logic behind it, like when you understand somewhat, it means, that some notion is being transferred FROM that person to you, if it helps you remembering, but, I am afraid, there is no very good algorithm behind it other than that.

Comment: like i know 
нравиться is kamy and 
любовь always takes kavo but when i use a new word i cant know which one is it

Comment: Yes, some of these confuse even native speakers. For example, some people say "согласно приказА", хотя правильно говорить "согласно приказУ".  Generally speaking, when you learn a a new verb, you are going to also have to learn how it is used with nouns. Most of the time, it should be obvious (e.g., because the use matches how it is in  English), other times, just another thing to learn

Comment: BTW, why "like" and "love" behave differently: "_Я_ люблю тебя", но "_Ты_ нравишься мне". The second case is passive voice.